# Tab Bar Item Shadow Effect

Tags: ios, user-interface, tabbar, tabbarcontroller

I don't want the default style of touching the tabBarItem, which is making the one choosing to be white and others be grey. I want to make them to be white all the time, and the one choosing having a rectangle containing the icon with darker color? Just like the one below.How can I achieve this?

Comment: You missed the image upload part.

Comment: Sorry I cant because I don't have enough reputation to do that.